# Oracle streams - waiting for redo when the redo file is gone forever

Tags: oracle, oracle-streams

I have streams configured, which stopped working after a while. 
To resync, I stopped all capture/apply processes and exported the tables from source to target.

After starting up again, it still says waiting for that same redo file.

Is it possible to "restart" streams from a current file?

Comment: I tried but doesn't work to me.
You can find my question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521870/oracle-11g-streams-replication-how-to-set-the-start-scn-of-an-existing-captur

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to "shift" your capture process ahead in time? You could try to switch your capture process to a certain SCN by invoking

```
DBMS_CAPTURE_ADM.ALTER_CAPTURE('YOUR_CAPTURE_NAME', start_scn => :SCN);
```

where `:SCN` is a valid system change number from which you want your messages to be captured. Take a look at DBMS_CAPTURE_ADM [description](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_cap_a.htm#i996962).

Comment: Hi, yes I want to shift the capture forward. I ended up re-creating the entire process since the tables were relatively small